# Connection refused to Python TCP server from C++ TCP client on LocalHost

Tags: python, c++, tcp

I'm trying to connect a simple TCP client written in C++ to a simple TCP server written in Python. I know that my server works, as I can connect a simple TCP client written in Python to it, but whenever I try to connect my C++ TCP client to my Python TCP server, I get a connection refused error.

Here is my Python TCP server code:

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9999
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print("Listening...")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Accepted connection!")
```

Here is my C++ TCP client code:

```
#ifdef __WIN32__

# include <winsock2.h>

#else
# include <sys/socket.h>
#endif

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include "Client.h"

    Client::Client(int port_number) {
        if (client_socket == -1) {
            //Create socket
            client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if (client_socket == -1) {
                perror("Could not create socket");
                return;
            }

            std::cout << "Socket created\n";
        }

        std::string address = "127.0.0.1";

        struct sockaddr_in server;
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(port_number);

        inet_pton(AF_INET, address.c_str(), &server.sin_addr);
        std::cout << "PORT: " << ntohs(server.sin_port) << std::endl;

        // Connect to remote server
        int connection_result = connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
        if (connection_result < 0) {
            perror("connect failed. Error");
            return;
        }

        std::cout << "Connected\n";
    }
```

And here is the TCP client's .h file:

```
class Client {
private:
public:
    int port_number;
    int client_socket = -1;
    int client_fd;

    Client(int port_number);
};
```

When I try to connect my TCP client to my TCP server, I get this error:

```
Socket created
PORT: 9999
connect failed. Error: Connection refused
```

I am running my C++ TCP client on Windows Linux Subsystem on my Windows machine.

I would greatly appreciate help in this matter.

Comment: Maybe there's a firewall blocking the port.

Comment: *"I am running my C++ TCP client on Windows Linux Subsystem on my Windows machine."* - and where is your server running? Also on WSL? Where did your Python client run? Make sure they are all running on the same system and in the same environment (WSL).

Comment: Connection refused should be the response when the port is unblocked, but no one is listening. If you can snoop in on localhost, check a packet trace and you should see a RST packet coming back.

Comment: Wait a sec. I doubt it still counts as localhost when you're running stuff in Windows and WSL. Yeah, basically what Steffen just said.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I will make my server run on WSL too now

Comment: There's a tool called `netcat`, which you can usually make use of for testing these things. It can act as both server and client in a TCP connection, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what was going wrong. My Python server was running on Windows, but my C++ client was running on WSL. This caused connection issues. I have changed my server so that it runs on WSL too, and this fixes the connection issue.

Comment: You were binding the server to `127.0.0.1`.  That only listens on "localhost".  Use `s.bind(('', PORT)` to listen on all interfaces.  Then (unless you have a firewall) it should work with Windows and WSL.